# Building Android - runtimeTest linkage with libld error

Tags: android, build, linker

Since I upgraded my gcc I can't seem to compile my Android 2.1 project.

Right now there is a linkage error:

```
out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/acc_intermediates/main.o: In function `symbolLookup(void*, char const*)':
/home/roeischuster/tdroid/system/core/libacc/tests/main.cpp:41: undefined reference to `dlsym'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/acc_intermediates/acc] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/accRuntimeTest_intermediates/runtimeTest.o: In function `symbolLookup':
/home/roeischuster/tdroid/system/core/libacc/tests/runtimeTest.cpp:66: undefined     reference to `dlsym'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/accRuntimeTest_intermediates/accRuntimeTest] Error 1
```

I have tried adding libld to LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES of system/core/libacc/tests/Androd.mk, but then I get:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libdl.so', needed by `out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/accRuntimeTest_intermediates/accRuntimeTest'.  Stop.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the error message - `undefined reference to 'dlsym'`, while trying to finish compiling and linking `main.cpp --> main.o --> main`, GNU linker `ld` does not know that function `dlsym` can be resolved by using the `dl` library. We can inform `gcc` or `ld` about `dl` library by passing an argument `--library dl` or `-ldl` in short.

For your particular case of cross-compilation in Android, getting back to the error message again:

```
/home/roeischuster/tdroid/system/core/libacc/tests/main.cpp:41: 
undefined reference to `dlsym'
```

You should find a file called `Android.mk` at `~/tdroid/system/core/libacc/tests/Android.mk`. To solve your compilation error, after each line of `include $(CLEAR_VARS)`, add a line that says `LOCAL_LDLIBS += -ldl`. Your `Android.mk` file should look like below now and if you do a `make` again after making the changes, everything should compile. Cheers :-).

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

# Executable for host
# ========================================================
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= acc 
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -ldl    
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
        main.cpp    
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
    libacc    
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := tests    
include $(BUILD_HOST_EXECUTABLE)

# Executable for target
# ========================================================
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= acc 
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -ldl    
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
        main.cpp \
    disassem.cpp    
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
    libacc    
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O0 -g      
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := tests    
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

# Runtime tests for host
# ========================================================
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= accRuntimeTest    
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -ldl    
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
        runtimeTest.cpp    
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
    libacc    
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := tests    
include $(BUILD_HOST_EXECUTABLE)

# Runtime tests for target
# ========================================================
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= accRuntimeTest

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -ldl    
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
        runtimeTest.cpp    
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
    libacc    
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O0 -g    
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := tests    
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```